# how to fix error in php ajax search feature as it shows only the last value of mysql table

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to create a tagging system for one of my projects and i was able to create a working tagging system in the end but the problem i face now is the tagging ajax search feature seems to be only fetching the last value of the uname table and not the other matches in that table.

so far, i tried the usual AJAX search feature method in my code by fetching the username from the tinymce editor and passed it to my php script using ajax in my js script but it doesn't bring the desired results of getting all the matching wildcard possibilities of other usernames except the last one.

PHP code:

```
$un=stripslashes($_POST['uname']);
$fn= stripslashes($_POST['fname']);
$ln= stripslashes($_POST['lname']);
$uname=  htmlentities($un);
$fname= htmlentities($fn);
$lname= htmlentities($ln);

try {
    $sql="select uname,avatar from user where fname like '%$fname%' or lname like '%$lname%' or uname like '%$uname%' and activated='1'";
    $stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    while ($row_s=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        if($row_s>0){
            $uname_s=$row_s['uname'];
            $photo_s=$row_s['avatar'];
            if($photo_s !=""){
                //  echo '<div class="show" align="left">';
                $notify=$uname_s;
                // echo '</div>';
            }  else {
                //  echo '<div class="show" align="left">';
                $notify=$uname_s;
                // echo '</div>'; 
            }
        }
    }
    $data=array("names"=>$notify); 
    echo json_encode($data);
} catch (PDOException $exc) {
    echo $exc->getMessage();
}
```

JS code:

```
var results = [];
$.ajax({
    url: "jsdropdown.php",
    data: {
        "(uname | fname | lname)": match[1]
    },
    async: false,
    complete: function(res) {
        results.push(res);
        // results=res;
        return res;
    },
    dataType: "json"
});
var dat=results[0].responseJSON;
var names=new Array(dat.names);
//alert(results);
alert(names);
//var names1=[results1.substring(50,85)];
$(editor.contentDocument.activeElement).atwho({
    at: "@",
    data: names
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $notify=$uname_s;
```

As `$notify` is a simple variable which can store only one result which will be the last one thats why get only last value.

You can use array to append the results.

something like

```
$notify[index++]=$uname_s;
```

Comment: i got the desired result now but i face a new problem how can i split a string in to an array in javascript. i tried this but it isn't giving any results `var dat=results[0].responseJSON;
          
          var names=new Array(dat.names);
          var name1=names.split(",");
      alert(name1);`